# Error Jasper Report Java: NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema. Estoy tratando de recompilar un proyecto que desarrollé con NetBeans 7 hace unos años, esto, porque el cliente decidió hacer unas modificaciones únicamente en costos, entonces, las modificaciones en si se realizaron en la función que genera esos costos, sin embargo, esta configuración la realicé en Apache Netbeans 12, recompilo, genero la aplicación pero me arroja el un error en consola y no me genera el recibo de pago sobre JasperReports como antes. Repito, no se modificó ningún formulario ni nada, solo costos, y no me genera el reporte. Este es el código de acción del botón:

```
private void JBtnImprimeReciboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
   this.folio=String.valueOf(this.JTxtFolio.getText());
    cuenta=JTxtNoCuenta.getText();
  //  this.cliente=String.valueOf(this.JTxtNoCliente.getText());
    this.nom=String.valueOf(this.JTxtNombre.getText());
    this.dire=String.valueOf(this.JTxtDireccion.getText());
    this.col=String.valueOf(this.JTxtColonia.getText());
    this.muni=String.valueOf(this.JTxtMunicipio.getText());
    this.tel=String.valueOf(this.JTxtTelefono.getText());
    this.rfc=String.valueOf(this.JTxtRfc.getText());
    this.fechacub=String.valueOf(this.JTxtFechaCubierta.getText());
    this.fechaapagar=String.valueOf(this.JTxtFechaaPagar.getText());
    this.mesestransc=String.valueOf(this.JTxtMesesTranscurridos.getText());
    this.rezagos=String.valueOf(this.JTxtRezagos.getText());
    this.recargos=String.valueOf(this.JTxtRecargos.getText());
    this.subtotal=String.valueOf(this.JTxtSubtotal.getText());
    this.total=String.valueOf(this.JTxtTotal.getText());
    
    try
    {
        Connection miConexion = EnlaceDB.GetConnection();
        String rutaRecibo = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/reportesMXVN/recibo.jasper";
        JasperReport recib = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(rutaRecibo);
        String Cfolio = JTxtFolio.getText();
        Map parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("Folio", Cfolio);
        JasperPrint recibo = JasperFillManager.fillReport(recib, parametros,miConexion);
        JRViewer ventanaVisor = new JRViewer(recibo);
        JDialog dialogo =new JDialog(this, true);
        dialogo.setSize(900, 700);
        dialogo.setTitle("Recibo de Pago");
        dialogo.getContentPane().add(ventanaVisor);
        dialogo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialogo.setVisible(true);
        /*ventanaVisor.setTitle("Recibo de Pago");
        ventanaVisor.setVisible(true);*/
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "ERROR AL GENERAR EL RECIBO DEL PAGO"+ex, "VERIFICAR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

y el error en consola es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/compilers/GroovyEvaluator
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClass(JRClassLoader.java:338)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassFromBytes(JRClassLoader.java:261)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractJavaCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractJavaCompiler.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.loadEvaluator(JRAbstractCompiler.java:320)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.loadEvaluator(JasperCompileManager.java:237)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createCalculator(JRFillDataset.java:428)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:430)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:78)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:58)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:52)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
at prykualiatl.JDlgRegPagos.JBtnImprimeReciboActionPerformed(JDlgRegPagos.java:1106)
at prykualiatl.JDlgRegPagos.access$700(JDlgRegPagos.java:17)
at prykualiatl.JDlgRegPagos$8.actionPerformed(JDlgRegPagos.java:601)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1021)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at prykualiatl.JDlgPagos.JBtnEditarActionPerformed(JDlgPagos.java:297)
at prykualiatl.JDlgPagos.access$100(JDlgPagos.java:12)
at prykualiatl.JDlgPagos$2.actionPerformed(JDlgPagos.java:112)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1716)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1663)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1021)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
at prykualiatl.JFrmMdi.JMItRegPagoActionPerformed(JFrmMdi.java:337)
at prykualiatl.JFrmMdi.access$500(JFrmMdi.java:5)
at prykualiatl.JFrmMdi$6.actionPerformed(JFrmMdi.java:141)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:369)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1020)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1064)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)`enter code here`
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.GroovyEvaluator
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:718)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 146 more
```

Podrían explicarme qué está mal y cómo puedo solucionarlo???

Answer (score 1):

Estás suponiendo que lo que hicieron hace 7 años es completamente compatible con lo que están usando ahora, tanto para compilar como para desplegar.

Si en producción pones la librería de, por ejemplo, jasperreports 4, debes usar esa misma al editar y compilar el jrxml. Ha habido cambios MUY grandes en los últimos 5 años que han roto esa compatibilidad.

El error específico se da porque en producción seguro está buscando el GroovyEvaluator pero esa clase no existe en versiones 4.x, sólo hasta 5.2 creo que aparece. Al compilar, iReport le pone las dependencias y demás, por eso el error. En general, classNoDeffound siempre se dará cuando compiles con algo y no lo pongas en producción.

Cambia la version de jasperreports en las dependencias que tienes en Netbeans, etc. Haz el downgrade.

Comment: Al querer realizar el downgrade, NetBeans me marca error en otro plugin que no me permite instalar la version de Jasper que usé en el proyecto.... tengo que codificar de nuevo o debería ser suficiente actualizando todas las librerías del proyecto en general???

Comment: Si no puedes compilar el reporte con la versión correcta de jasperreports, vas a seguir encontrando el mismo noclassdeffound. Posiblemente necesites usar iReport 5 o anterior para generar los `.jasper`